Firebase Integration in .NET MAUI iOS Project Causes Missing Swift Libraries Error(.NET 8)
I'm attempting to integrate Firebase and Firebase Crashlytics into my .NET MAUI project using Visual Studio on macOS. It worked fine before I updated the NuGet packages. Now, the app fails on iOS (both simulator and real device), showing the following error:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8022/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(3,3): Error: clang++ exited with code 1:
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility50'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFileProvider'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftOSLog'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibilityDynamicReplacements'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility51'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swif

What I tried:

Updated Firebase and Firebase Crashlytics packages.
Updated .NET SDK.
Modified Info.plist with FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled and
UIBackgroundModes.
Added Swift libraries to .csproj file:


<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="libswiftCore.dylib" />
    <Reference Include="libswiftFoundation.dylib" />
    <!-- Add other required libraries -->
</ItemGroup>


How can I resolve this issue and ensure the app runs on iOS?


May I know the exact name and version of the Firebase and Firebase Crashlytics packages you are using? 2. It worked fine before I updated the NuGet packages, have you tried to downgrade to the versions which worked before? 3. What is your current MAUI version, can be viewed via cmd: dotnet workload list.


@AlexandarMay-MSFT I have the same issue and is using:








2. Need to upgrade to get better crash logs in firebase
3. maui 8.0.7/8.0.100
@Cliffhanger 1. Please try to delete XamarinBuildDownload caches at ~/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload and build again. 2. Please check the README instructions:https://github.com/AdamEssenmacher/GoogleApisForiOSComponents

The github issue referenced in this post seem to have resolved the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78605885/how-to-resolve-clang-error-missing-auto-linked-swift-libraries?noredirect=1#comment138590797_78605885

I got the exact same issue when updating to Plugin.Firebase 3.0.0, had to rollback to v2, I tried all the linking and none of that worked for me
