How to Resolve Clang++ Error: Missing Auto-Linked Swift Libraries?
I have been migrating my MAUI project which is in .NET 6 to latest .NET 8 version and I am facing this issue while I try to debug my project keeping IOS simulator as a target platform.
clang++ exited with code 1:
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility50'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFileProvider'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftOSLog'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibilityDynamicReplacements'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility51'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swif

    

I am not sure what is causing this error?
These are the versions of the devices and tools that I am using currently.



MAC - MAC OS sonoma version 14.5




XCODE version - 15.4




Visual studio - Visual Studio 2022 17.10



Tried clean rebuild couple of times,but getting the same error.
Also upgraded the packages and the Xcode, Still the same issue exists.
Any help on how to fix this issue is much appreciated. Thanks

Do you bind native library in your project? Here is an issue on GitHub, Issue binding iOS native library.

Adding this to my .csproj file worked for me:
  <Target Name="LinkWithSwift" DependsOnTargets="_ParseBundlerArguments;_DetectSdkLocations" BeforeTargets="_LinkNativeExecutable">
<PropertyGroup>
    <_SwiftPlatform Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('iossimulator-'))">iphonesimulator</_SwiftPlatform>
    <_SwiftPlatform Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('ios-'))">iphoneos</_SwiftPlatform>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <_CustomLinkFlags Include="-L" />
    <_CustomLinkFlags Include="/usr/lib/swift" />
    <_CustomLinkFlags Include="-L" />
    <_CustomLinkFlags Include="$(_SdkDevPath)/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/$(_SwiftPlatform)" />
</ItemGroup>

